# Clojure sub arrays

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to learn Clojure and Functional Programming in general, and for this I'm tring to resolve exercises from [Codingbat](http://codingbat.com/). I'm stuck when I have to find a subarray [1 2 3] from another sub array. from the page:

> Given an array of ints, return True if .. 1, 2, 3, .. appears in the
>   array somewhere.

I would love, not the answer per se, but the ideas of how could I solve. Well, that's almost equal to the answer but any idea will be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Alex deleted an answer well worth voting for :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a combination of [`some`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some) and [`partition`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/partition):

```
(some #{[1 2 3]} (partition 3 1 some-collection))
```

Note that the above does not return a boolean result (but it can still be used as test in conditionals). If you really want a boolean result you can use [`boolean`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/boolean)

Answer (score 5):

take it from thinking in "items in the array" to functions that take sequences and return sequences. This decomplexts the task of matching and deciding if what you matched solves your problem. (Im fairly sure that decomplect is ONLY in the Clojure dictionary)

in general:

- from the input data create a sequence that will contain what you are looking for:
  `autotestbed.core> (partition 3 1 (range 10))

  ((0 1 2) (1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5) (4 5 6) (5 6 7) (6 7 8) (7 8 9))`
- then from that sequence extract just the parts that fit your criteria:
   `(filter your-predicate-here (partition ...)`
- then decide if your answer has been found:
   (some true? ....)

in larger example some people would choose to devide this into several functions and then compose them.

---

To address your original question: (for thous whom google brings from the question title)

the `subvec` function returns subvectors in order-1 time

```
user>(subvec (vec (range 1000)) 10 20)
[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```